# Как уменьшить область действия UI button в Unity3d?

Tags: unity3d, ui

Есть UI button , которая имеет большую область действия
(сама кнопка не большого размера , но вот вокруг пустого,прозрачного пространства много(картинка в png).

Могу ли я вручную задать область действия кнопки(желательно не через код)?

Comment: под "большая область действия" вы имеете ввиду область, в границах которой кнопка реагирует на клики?

Comment: стандартными методами юнити нельзя,надо вручную отслеживать координату клика и проверять входит ли она в область png картинки

Comment: @MikhailDeyman Да.

Comment: Так то это возможно и без всяких проверок, входит ли клик в область картинки, картинка - это лишь компонент кнопки. Надо убрать этот компонент и добавить картинку, как дочерний элемент кнопки, а там уже размер подобрать не проблема.

Comment: Вообще говоря, у картинок есть галочка **Raycast Target**. Убираем ее у имеющейся картинки и навешиваем пустую картинку нужного размера и ставим галочку там. Это вы имеете в виду под "областью действия"?